# Bold contact item in LaTeX AltaCV

Tags: cv, altacv

I am using the AltaCV template for my CV, 2 columns.

This is the part about contact details:

```
\personalinfo{%
  \email{name@domain.com}
  \phone{123456789}
  \linkedin{my_linkedin}
  \location{i will move to city xyz next month}
  \github{my_github}
}
```

I want to set the name of the city "xyz" in bold.

If I set the text in bold as usual:

```
\location{i will move to city \textbf{xyz} next month}
```

It does not work properly. The text is repeated twice:

[image: output]

Any ideas? Maybe modifying the personalinfo field in the altacv.cls?

Thanks in advance

P.s. here is the full code if you want to try too. You also need the *altacv* template from Overleaf.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,ragged2e,withhyper]{altacv}

% Change the page layout if you need to
\geometry{left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm}

% The paracol package lets you typeset columns of text in parallel
\usepackage{paracol}

% Change the font if you want to, depending on whether
% you're using pdflatex or xelatex/lualatex
\ifxetexorluatex
  % If using xelatex or lualatex:
  \setmainfont{Roboto Slab}
  \setsansfont{Lato}
  \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\else
  % If using pdflatex:
  \usepackage[rm]{roboto}
  \usepackage[defaultsans]{lato}
  % \usepackage{sourcesanspro}
  \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\fi

% Change the colours if you want to
\definecolor{SlateGrey}{HTML}{2E2E2E}
\definecolor{LightGrey}{HTML}{666666}
\definecolor{DarkPastelRed}{HTML}{450808}
\definecolor{PastelRed}{HTML}{8F0D0D}
\definecolor{GoldenEarth}{HTML}{E7D192}
\colorlet{name}{black}
\colorlet{tagline}{PastelRed}
\colorlet{heading}{DarkPastelRed}
\colorlet{headingrule}{GoldenEarth}
\colorlet{subheading}{PastelRed}
\colorlet{accent}{PastelRed}
\colorlet{emphasis}{SlateGrey}
\colorlet{body}{LightGrey}

% Change some fonts, if necessary
\renewcommand{\namefont}{\Huge\rmfamily\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\personalinfofont}{\footnotesize}
\renewcommand{\cvsectionfont}{\LARGE\rmfamily\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cvsubsectionfont}{\large\bfseries}


% Change the bullets for itemize and rating marker
% for \cvskill if you want to
\renewcommand{\itemmarker}{{\small\textbullet}}
\renewcommand{\ratingmarker}{\faCircle}

% for today's date
\usepackage[ddmmyyyy]{datetime}
\newdateformat{mydateformat}{\THEDAY/\THEMONTH/\THEYEAR}

\begin{document}
\name{MyName}
\tagline{MyPosition}


\personalinfo{%
  \email{name@domain.com}
  \phone{123456789}
  \linkedin{my_linkedin}
  \location{i will move to city \textbf{xyz} next month}
  \github{my_github}
}
  
\makecvheader

{\color{headingrule}\hrule}

\vspace{4em}

\mydateformat\today

\vspace{\baselineskip}

BODY OF COVER LETTER

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sure, I edited the post with more details!

Comment: Please provide a full-fledged MWE, i.e. a (minimal) piece of code that we can copy, paste & compile as is, that shows your problem.

Comment: Added a piece of code!